# Is it possible to use the sails.js console when lifting a Treeline.js project?

Tags: sails.js, treeline

I'm using the Treeline developer beta, and I'm a newbie with Sails.js as well. I come from a RoR background and frequently use the console to "check" how my app is actually working. I love the idea of using the console in Sails.js. Is there a way I can configure my system or my app so that I can use the sails console after I "treeline lift" the project?

Answer (score 2):

There's not currently a way to use the Sails console while your app is connected to the Treeline "mothership".  But don't forget--Treeline apps *are* Sails.js apps.  You can always use `sails console` to poke around your app; it just won't be automatically updated with changes you make in Treeline until the next time you do `treeline preview` (or its alias, `treeline lift`).